# Redux Container and mapDispatchToProps

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm using react-redux to Redux together with React. Console log in App.js for this.props and this.props.fetchProducts return an empty object and undefined respectively.

The first question I want to ask is - why is that the case and how do I fix it.

The second question I have is - how do I pass down store to CartPage and MainPage? Or is that not recommended since we should use connect to pass whatever state value we need to our component instead?

Much thanks.

**index.js**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ProductsReducer,
  PriceReducer,
  UserReducer
});

const store = compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))(createStore)(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(this.props.fetchProducts);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch> 
        <Route exact path='/cart' render={() => <CartPage />} />
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => <MainPage />} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

**AppContainer**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FetchProducts } from '../actions/FetchProducts';
import App from '../App';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchProducts: () => dispatch(FetchProducts())
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: OP you can read this first: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components. Basically `<Provider>` is not enough; you need to wrap container components inside `connect` from `react-redux` to get data from redux store.

Comment: @blaz opps I forgot to add my AppContainer. Edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `App` with `AppContainer` in your `index.js`. You always need to use container components wrapped in `connect` from react-redux to retrieve data from store.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContainer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks I got it working! I found out that using component works too as long as it contains a container. My mistake was not using the container be it directly or indirectly through a component that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

1- Connect your app component to store using mapStateToProps, then console the result.

2- to pass down the store to main page, i will prefer to connect your main page also to store using  mapStateToProps or you can pass the data you want to main page through custom props as

```
<Route exact path='/cart' render={() => <CartPage />} fetchProductDetails={this.props.fecthProduct}/>
```

Comment: opps I forgot to add my AppContainer. Edited post.

Comment: to get the data from Store use "mapStatetoProps". assuming u have already set reducer properly. currently in place of mapStateToProps u are sending null.